# Save variable when view controller is pushed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have two view controllers: A table view that is seen when the app loads and A controller that is pushed when a cell is selected. I have a variable in one of the table view declarations that needs to be transferred to the other view controller when it is pushed.The variable gives each table cell a number ([objectAtIndex row] + 1) so that the cell on top is 1. the next is 2. ect. I need that variable so various used in the view controller. How can I do this? Thank you.

Here is the code in the first View controller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [atableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
}

BNRItem *p = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


//Variable that I need in the other view:
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d. %@",[indexPath row] + 1, p];


[[cell textLabel] setText:string];

 return cell;  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways but the two simple ways are here...

One simple way in this

save value in user default

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"Your Value" forKey:@"Your Key"];
```

retrieve value in next controller, write in viewWillAppear

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Your Key"];
```

---

2nd way is

```
   MessageBoxViewController *msgBoxController = [[MessageBoxViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MessageBoxViewController" bundle:nil];

[msgBoxController setReceverArray:urArray]; 

[self.navigationController pushViewController:msgBoxController animated:YES];
[msgBoxController release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use key-value coding/observing around `textLabel` from one controller class to the other. If `UITableViewCell` is KVC-compliant then you can get KVO for free by registering an observer on its `text` property (I use MacOS, not iOS so I don't know if this is the case). If not, before you set the text call `[self willChangeValueForKey:]` for some key property shadowing the cell's text and afterwards call `[self didChangeValueForKey:]`. Assuming your other class has set an observer on the first controller class it will get a `observeValueForKeyPath:` notification.

UPDATE: in response to the request for clarification.

Say I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar`. I want `Foo` to be notified whenever a property (i.e instance variable) of `Bar` changes. If `Bar` has been written in an appropriate fashion, it will be key-value coding compliant. This means that its properties are accessible via a so-called key path, which is an encoded string representation. Let's say that `Bar` is declared like this:

.h

```
@interface Bar : public NSObject
@property (assign,readwrite) NSInteger x;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "Bar.h"
@implementation Bar
@synthesize x;

...

@end
```

The combination of the `@property` and `@synthesize` declarations will have automatically generated a pair of getter and setter methods, called `x` and `setX` respectively. IF you have done this, then `x` is accessible using KVC. A class can do something like the following:

```
Bar *bar=[[Bar alloc] init];
NSInteger barX=[bar valueForKey:@"x"];
[bar setValue:2 forKeyPath:@"x"]; // really needs an NSNumber wrapper object
```

For your purposes, this becomes useful because classes that are KVC-compliant can be made key-value observing (KVO) compliant. To implement KVO, you call the `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` method on the object to be observed and implement the `observeValueforKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method in the object you wish to be doing the observing. Thus, for an instance of class `Foo` to be informed every time the `x` property of an instance of `Bar` changes, you could do something like the following:

```
Foo *foo=[[Foo alloc] init];
Bar *bar=[[Bar alloc] init];

[bar addObserver:foo forKeyPath:@"x" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
   context:NULL];
```

and in the implementation of the `Foo` class, you would override the observer method

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
   change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
   if[keyPath isEqualToString:@"x"]
      {
      // extract new value from change dictionary
      }
}
```

Every time `bar` changed its `x` property using `[self setX:<new value>]` a message would be sent to the `observeValueForKeyPath:` method of `foo`. Note that in order for KVO to be triggered, the setter method must be used. It is not enough to simply say `x=2;` inside an instance method.

All of this is given to you free as part of the `NSObject` (or iOS equivalent) implementation. The docs are available from Apple's developer site. They are Key Value Coding Programming Guide and Key Value Observing Programming Guide.

Comment: Sorry @David but Im very new to IOS and I do not know what KVC or KVO is. Would it be possible for you to give me a more concrete example?